# Would this be considered "breaking the rules of hooks"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I have a compound component that is used to build a bunch of different (but similar) screens in a react native app. Data comes from a CMS, and depending on the value of a prop called `type` it needs to have different state variables, different validation, etc. I've written a config object who's methods map to the values of `type`, and contain the state and functions needed for each use case. The pattern looks like this (edited for example sake):

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const MyComponent = props => {
  const { type } = props; // possible values of type are 'A', 'B', 'C'

  const config = {
    A() {
      const [value, setValue] = useState('');
      
      function onChange({ target }) {
        setValue(target.value);
      }
      return {
        value,
        onChange
      }
    },
    B() {
      // ...
      return {
        value: '',
        onChange: () => {}
      }
    },
    C() {
      // ...
      return {
        value: '',
        onChange: () => {}
      }
    }
  }[type]();

  return <input value={config.value} onChange={config.onChange} />
};

export default MyComponent;
```

BUT!

In the react [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level) it says this:

> Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions.

My question is - does the above example violate the rules of hooks? It seems to work for what I need it to, but I suspect that it may cause problems. Would appreciate any thoughts / discussion. Cheers!

Comment: Since you mention "react native", it would be worth adding the `react-native` tag to make sure it's seen by the best audience for the question.

Comment: Hmm. This just really makes me think of a Factory pattern instead of quite like this. Your main Component would take the type and return an A or a B (etc) component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes.

Long answer:

React depends on hooks to be called in the exact same order between renders (I believe internally the hooks are stored in a linked list, which is altered on mounting and unmounting of the component, if the order changes between renders without a mount and unmount, React has no way to know which hook belongs to which component).

Because your rendering from a CMS, the value of `type` is unlikely to change between renders, so you probably will never get in to trouble with this particular use case, but it is a bad habit to get in to, and there is almost certainly a better way to handle what you are trying to do. Maybe write a hook that takes type as an argument?

```
function useMyHook(type:string) {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');
  const onChange = useMemo(() => {
    if (type = 'A')
      return () => doXyz()
  }, [type])
  return {state, onChange}
}
```

This is contrived, but hopefully will get you thinking of alternate approaches to your problem.